# How to run a command interactively using python?

Tags: python, subprocess, aws-cli

I want to run "aws configure" and pass the access key and secret key values programmatically using python.

I tried

```
list = ['aaaa', 'bbb']
subprocess.Popen(['aws', 'configure']+list)
```

did not work.

Comment: Don't do this. Use the Python library for AWS, [boto](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you explain why he shouldn't do like that

Comment: any errors while running the subprocess?

Comment: @Argus, It does not throw an error. If I run the above command with valid credentials, the above line prints the below output:`>>> subprocess.Popen(['aws', 'configure']+list)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x110150dd8>
>>> usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:`

Comment: Is it possible you're missing a `shell=True` definition?

Comment: @st0ler I tried that too:                                                                                                 '>>> subprocess.Popen(['aws', 'configure', 'AAA', 'aaa'], shell=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x1101d0e10>
>>> usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: too few arguments
`